# Twitch API Integration into Discord Bot - More efficient way?

Tags: c#, json, twitch, discord, discord.net

I am currently writing a Discord Bot in C#. I have most the bot done but for this next update I am wanting to add on the capability of checking if the Streamer has Gone live. Currently I am polling the Twitch API and Pulling the JSON File that it has and checking whether or not the JSON Stream Object is Null or Not. But this takes 3-5 min after the streamer to go live before it finally sees that Stream is not Null even though I poll the JSON every 5 seconds. Is there anyway to do this more efficiently? My code is Below:

```
       private const string Url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/streamer";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

        request.Method = "Get";
        request.Timeout = 12000;
        request.ContentType = "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json";
        request.Headers.Add("Client-ID", "ID");

        using (var s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
            {

                var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
                var jsonStream = jsonObject["stream"];

                // twitch channel is online if stream is not null.
                LastTwitchStatus = jsonStream.Type != JTokenType.Null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's intended behavior of Twitch API.
They are definitely more focused on pushing their horsepower to streaming, not immediate data provision through API.

While there might be a limitation like this, you can try scrapping the page if timing is crucial and you don't want to wait 3-5 min for something that already happened.
One idea is to poll page each 5s or so and then query the HTML document for something characteristic that distinguish offline and online channel.

## Idea for scrapping in JavaScript (just replicate in .NET):

For example, I have tried to query user pages (https://www.twitch.tv/**username**) in JavaScript with:

```
$(".recent-past-broadcast").length > 0
```

and for user that is not broadcasting it yields `true` while for broadcasting user it yields `false`. Problem might be for user with no recent broadcasts history though.

You can try checking videos page (https://www.twitch.tv/**username**/videos/all) for their live indicator too like:

```
$(".cn-livestatus__circle").length > 0
```

It will yield `true` for streaming user and `false` for the one that does not stream (even if he/she is online).

Of course that's least efficient way on doing this and requires lots of download as compared to just polling but... still it seems more up to date than asking API every 5s and still getting actual state delayed by 3-5min.

Just replicate querying like above in .NET and you're there.

You could also mix two approaches and if you see that someone started streaming, just disable page scrapping and swap to only API calls for checking if you're up-to-date still.

## Useful tooling for scrapping:

For parsing HTML documents use parsers like **AngleSharp** to do this in .NET: 
https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp